# Marketing Cloud Conversion Tracking - alias=%%link_name%%

Tags: marketing-cloud

Okay, QQ - I'm banging my head on the wall. We've enabled conversion tracking in links and get links like this https://www.url.com/?j=12345&sfmc_sub=2412473819&l=12348_HTML&u=23132146&mid=2355325253&jb=1&alias=%%linkname%%. The part we're having issues with is in the URL the alias comes through as literally %%link_name%%. This is causing other parameters not to be captured by our CDP (as in our WAP added querystrings. Our link has an alias:  URL- w/ conversion tracking .  Support told us to turn on Smart URL encoding and we did in our dev environment but it did nothing. Anyone else have anything we should try or have had this problem? About to just stop coding our emails with conversion="true" if we can't figure it out.

Comment: how/where are you adding alias=%%linkname%%?

Comment: Does the beahvior change if you add this to your WAC string?

Comment: @EazyE It just adds it automatically when I put conversion=“true” inside of the A tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this you need to have alias=%%linkname%% in your WAC string configured within parameter manager and not within your conversion string

Your [conversion string](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_insert_emaillink.htm&type=5) should simply be
`j=%%jobid%%&sfmc_sub=%%SubscriberID%%&l=%%List_%%&u=%%JobURLID%%&mid=%%MemberID%%&jb=%%_JobSubscriberBatchID%%`

Your conversion page code can pass any value you want for `<link_alias>` this doesn't have to match the alias of the link in the email

Comment: I’ll add this to WAC string on Monday and report back. This is currently on our conversion parameters. I agree documentation doesn’t mention it and should only be those above. But, that seems not to be the case. I assume that support could remove that from the conversion string?

Comment: Is there a way to access the conversion string or is it only support that can modify it?

Comment: I asked support to remove the alias string and that worked and I placed the alias inside the WAC as you mentioned and it worked flawlessly.